# How could I get contents of simpleXML array object when I encode it into JSON?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I have a php function that fetches and returns tweets data from twitter as simplexml object.I could get its contents by using php syntax. Here is php function

```
<?php

    function searchResults($q) {
    $host = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . urlencode( $q ) . "&rpp=100";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    //Raw xml
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
    return $xml;
    }            
?>
```

If I call it like

```
$xml = searchResults('xyz');
```

I could fetch its contents like

```
echo $xml->content.''.$xml->author->name;
```

Now I need to return it from php function in JSON format. Like

```
return json_encode($xml);
```

in spite of

```
return $xml;
```

So how do now I get same 'content' and 'author->name' etc contents from it in JSON format when I decode json.

Comment: Not an answer but note that you may be able to use `simplexml_load_file($url)` directly if you don't need any special curl options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you're accessing it back from PHP, there are two ways:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->author->name;
```

or

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $arr['author']['name'];
```

If you are accessing it using JavaScript, it should be:

```
alert(jsObject.author.name);
```

Comment: How do I loop through json object.I use this format              "$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->author->name;"
 Like I could loop through xml " foreach($xml->entry as $status) {
       echo status->content;
               }"

Comment: Yes, you can use `foreach` on a `stdClass` object (i.e.: what `json_decode` returns).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the XML for any other reason than to return it as JSON, why not use json format as the response for the Twitter API call?
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blablabla
This returns the response in a JSON string that you could just return.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
<?php

function searchResults($q) {
    $host = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" . urlencode( $q ) . "&rpp=100";

    $raw_json = file_get_contents($host);

    return $raw_json;
}

?>
```